# Vue JS : Getting Unique ID and Value of an array of input at the same time

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

I am new in Vue and still learning using it. I am learning to use the [Element UI](https://element.eleme.io) for Vue UI. Specifically, I'm trying the [`Input Number Component`](https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input-number), for an array of data. Let say I have my data like this:

```
dataList = [{
    id: 1,
    productName: "ABC",
    qty: 1
}, {
    id: 2,
    productName: "DEF",
    qty: 2
}];
```

And the element goes like this:

```
<div v-for="(item, index) in dataList" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <el-input-number v-model="item.qty" @change="handleChange"></el-input-number>    
</div>
```

And for the script goes like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    handleChange = function (value) {
        console.log(value); /* I need the item.id also not just the qty value */
    };
</script>
```

from the function `handleChange()` I only can get the value of input number, but not the item id that I've assign in the element. How can I get both of that (item.id and value)?

I was expecting a js function like this could work, but it didnt:

```
handleChange = function(item, value) { /* */ }
```

I've been trying to google for some answer, but the answer always showing only 1 parameter that i can acquire from `change` event.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass your value (`$event`) as first parameter and the other parameter as the second one :

```
 <div v-for="(item, index) in dataList" v-bind:key="item.id">
   <el-input-number v-model="item.qty" @change="handleChange($event,item.id)"></el-input-number>    
</div>
```

Script :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     handleChange = function (value,id) {
        console.log(value,id); 
     };
</script>
```